# Was this answer deleted appropriately?

Tags: support, moderation

Unfortunately, @caleb was either bored or having a bad day.

My answer, which was accepted by the OP as the correct answer, was swiftly deleted by @caleb.

I really, really, really, really, really would have appreciated either a small edit (perhaps even by @caleb) or the opportunity to edit it myself so that I would not be robbed of 30+ reputation points!!

Can you please help?

Thanks!

[How literally do you take and universally apply what Jesus said?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6475/how-literally-do-you-take-and-universally-apply-what-jesus-said/6480#comment17331_6480)

Comment: Jim, while Marc is a developer for Stack Exchange (and because of that has a diamond) he is *not* a community moderator here. Please keep that in mind when addressing moderation issues. Complaints about moderators are best directed at meta (like your doing) or by emailing the SE team email that is linked at the bottom of every page under contact us.

Comment: @wax eagle: Thanks! I just didn't know who else to appeal to. Caleb made a *very* arbitrary and capricious decision on my post, and I needed other moderators to look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Just asking here on meta would be fine, I expect

Comment: @WaxEagle while the email approach is an option, I would *hope* that it is at least attempted to discuss the issue on meta first. Depends on the nature of the issue, though, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for editing this. I have undeleted it.

Answer (score 8):

Caleb was responding to the *community* flagging process.  That means that one or more people flagged the answer as requiring moderator attention.  The flagging is anonymous, so you won't know who objected unless they tell you.

I checked to see, but I didn't flag the answer, though I thought about it.  For me, the problem with the answer was the two questions:

> Have you ever heard of a martyr?

and:

> Doesn't that count?

Caleb noted the answer might be taken as sarcastic, to which I agree.  There are ways to make your answer without coming off as derisive or arrogant.

The good news is that if you edit the answer to fix the tone, and flag it for moderator attention, there's a good chance the answer can be restored.

---

Now for the meta-question: I don't think you do yourself any favors by pitting one moderator against another.  Caleb did what his conscience said was right in responding to the community flagging on that answer.  Every day moderators need to make decisions about what's best for the site.  It's a difficult job that will certainly get harder as the site grows.  Each one knows that the others are doing their best and won't question each other's motives lightly.  Moderators must show solidarity with each other.  For the good of the site, we most allow them to do their work without hindrance or complaint if possible.

If a moderator *does* have a bad day or whatever, we shouldn't call them out publicly or beg another moderator to interfere.  Bringing the matter to meta isn't a bad idea, but keep it low key (which you didn't do), non-confrontational (ditto), and address the issue objectively (you didn't really do that either).  You might have quoted your answer here (for people who can't see deleted answers [I can]) and asked how it could be improved.

Finally, "robbed of 30+ reputation points!!" sounds simultaneously shallow and hysterical.

Answer (score 6):

> @Marc Gravell

Important: I do not claim to represent the community on this site; my diamond is an accident of working as a developer for SE. Any content etc issues should be addressed to the moderators and community of this site.

The only times I act unilaterally on this site is when removing blatant trolling or other very inappropriate content. To act otherwise would be disruptive to the community, and frankly I try to keep my actions "clean" since I do not represent the consensus position.

Thus I defer all content opinions here to the community here on meta, and note that the moderators here act *on behalf of* the community. That doesn't automatically make every decision perfect, but most actions can be undone too.

Finally: note that I have deliberately written this **before** reviewing the question in, er, question: so everything I say here is general policy and does not specifically relate to any particular scenario.

That said, I would certainly hope (and glancing up it seems the case) that the moderators involved would be willing to discuss the issue constructively with you.

Answer (score 5):

Having a bit of a backstage view add it were, I'm pretty sure boredom wasn't an issue and it was actually a pretty good day for me. I'm sorry you think it was "arbitrary and capricious", but if you think it was a bad call on my part I'm happy to discuss it. You are always welcome to take concerns to the SE team, but don't forget there are other local site moderators around too. Also, if you have a concern with someone, often bringing it up with that person in discussion I'd a good place to start. Here are a couple other detail points:

- You can get the reputation points back of the answer gets un deleted. You can fix the issue with the content, then flag it for a moderator to review. I already left you a comment noting I thought the general idea of your content was on point, just the tone had an issue. Fix that and flag it!
- If a moderator is involved in the content of a flag, we always have other moderators review it. All off our moderators have a track record off stepping out and letting another mod make calls if there is a dispute. Since you didn't even try to discuss this with me, I'm not sure we even got to the dispute stage.
- I didn't feel like I could edit to fix the content problem. The issue I noted was how sarcastic the leading remark was. Since there basically want any more content that addressed the question other than that remark, I thought it needed to be your fix. You still have that option.

Comment: Typo: `add` -> `as`.